# Does defining a non-class private function means anything in Python?

Tags: function, python

```
def __f():
  print 1

def _f():
  print 1
```

I tried import and it's accessible:

```
>>> import test1
>>> test1._f()
1
```

Does it mean anything? I want to write some helper functions which aren't class-based. Then I want to hide certain low-level, concrete functions, and leaving only high-level function (view them as APIs) accessible to users to use.

For example:

test1.copy() will call another helper function in the same file which does some extra checking, but I don't want to expose that to user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private functions / Variables enforcement in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559256/private-functions-variables-enforcement-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The single leading underscore is a Python naming convention.  A number of tools rely on that convention.  For example *help()* will ignore single underscored names.  Using `from somemodule import *` will also ignore single underscored names.

The double leading underscore triggers name mangling (prefixing the name with the class name and a single leading underscore).  It is used to create thread-local references.  That allows intra-class calls that won't be accidentally broken by a subclass.  There is a nice example of this in the tutorial at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables .

Lastly, there is the special method naming convention of two leading underscores *and* two trailing underscores.  Those names are used by the interpreter to implement operators and to implement a number of standard protocols (i.e. iterators, context managers, pickling, etc).  See http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html for a nice write-up on the special methods.

Comment: Thank you. I've kindly accepted Li-aung Yip's request :)  Thanks, Raymond.

Answer (score 3):

The leading underscore convention is just that - a **convention** respected by polite programmers.

A leading underscore is a hint to other programmers that `_function()` is an internal implementation detail and shouldn't be used externally. There's nothing stopping them from calling `_function()` - but by doing so they're ignoring your hint that the implementation of `_function()` could change at any time. If something breaks, they get to keep both pieces.

The Python interpreter does not **enforce** any kind of restriction.

Comment: Thanks. I keep on forgetting about that.

Comment: Two leading underscores, however, are more than a convention. They have a special meaning when used inside a class definition.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a fairly established nomenclature convention, which ain't nothing. Also, it affects `from [module] import *`, which only imports functions not prefixed with underscores.

Comment: I believe it also affects `help(module)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have forgotten about that trick, although it's a trick since user can still do `import test1`. Thanks.

Comment: Note `from [module] import *` is horrible practice - it pollutes your namespace and can produce exciting name clashes. Don't do it in production code.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that, Li-aung :)

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly there actually was not a clean way to make any function private in python. The language is not intended to work this way. The underscore notation is just a common protocol among the developers, to denote something which probably is private or hidden.

There however might be a way to simulate private functionality. The first thing which pops in my head is using traceback module and then inspect a calling instance, to see if it matches the expected.  This by no way is something what I would do in my projects, and I would strongly advise against this, but if you absolutely cant live without it, that might be a way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's been a long time reading my introductory book. Nice review, I guess :)

Comment: You can do horrible things like monkey-patching the `__call__()` method, and so forth. Let's **not** talk about that... *shudders*

Comment: It could also use a hand-rolled module (subclass module and override `__getattribute__` to check for access rights... But yeah, don't do it :)